# javascript/jquery tabs not working in IE7, 8 or 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, tabs

This code works in every browser except, IE7, 8 and 9. I know I can use jquery tabs, but I like doing things differently to learn more native javascript.  Open the fiddle in IE and you will see what I mean.  Open it in any other browser, it will work. Somebody please tell me what I am doing wrong. Thanks

[tab links fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Chris22/rL9Mj/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In IE9, `this.pathname` returns `_display/`, but in Chrome, it's `/_display/`.

In both IE9 and Chrome `window.location.pathname` is `/_display/`.

So the `this.pathname == window.location.pathname` fails in IE.

Updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/rL9Mj/1/

Comment: rocket, thanks. how did you find out what IE returns?  so if i can't use the `this` for pathname, what can i use to make the path comparison? thanks

Comment: @Chris22: I just used `console.log` :-P  You can use `this.pathname`, you just need to prepend a `/` (if one isn't there already).  `var pathname = this.pathname[0] === '/' ? this.pathname : '/'+this.pathname;`